# How to obtain the attributes of a saml response sent by Azure Active Directory?

Tags: google-app-engine, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, python-3.4, saml-2.0

I have a saml response that gives me azure active directory when doing the process with saml 2.0, the whole process is done normally, I send a saml request and the azure active directory returns the saml response, to do the whole process I have based on this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications), I've been reading a bit and I've noticed that Azure AD in the saml response sends the values within this tag:

```
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>VALUE HERE</xenc:CipherValue
</xenc:CipherData>
```

And not inside:

```
<AttributeStatement><Attribute Name="IDPEmail"><AttributeValue>administrator@contoso.com</AttributeValue></Attribute></AttributeStatement>
```

as specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp#sample-saml-request-and-response-messages). The question is, how to get the true values that azure active directory is sent to me and not these encoded values, I am using Python 3 and Google App Engine, in addition to mentioning azure active directory and saml 2.0 to do the login process, I leave the SAML response complete in this [url](https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cbb225f3) in case it serves to give a better context to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, the SAML response you are getting is encrypted. Specifically Azure is encrypting its assertions (including the ones you are looking for) inside an encrypted body called `CipherData`.

You have two options:
1 - Disable SAML response encryption. 
Azure AD calls SAML response encryption as `SAML token encryption` which is a bit confusing. You can follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/howto-saml-token-encryption) to disable the response. You must have uploaded an encryption public key/cert  before.

2 - Configure your service provider to supported encrypted SAML responses.

Answer (score 0):

The SAML token is encrypted.

You need to get the client side certificate used for this and use that to decrypt it.